# How to solve this IVP with $g$ continuous and $f$ Lipschitz.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

Let $f,g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ functions such that $g$ is continuous and $f$ is Lipschitz. Consider the IVP

$$ \frac{dx}{dt}=\sigma(t,x)\quad x(t_0)=x_0$$

where $\sigma:\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ is defined by
$$ \sigma(t,x)=(f(x_1),g(x_1)x_2)$$

for all $t\in \mathbb{R}$ and $x=(x_1,x_2)\in \mathbb{R}^2$. Prove that the given IVP has unique solution in every interval (where it is defined). ¿Can we take off the assumption that $f$ is Lipschitz and obtain the same conclusion?

Can somebody give me a hint whit this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above equation is essentially $2$ equations -
\begin{align*}
\frac{dx_1}{dt} &= f(x_1) \\
\frac{dx_2}{dt} &= g(x_1)x_2
\end{align*}
As $f(x)$ is Lipschitz, the $1st$ IVP has a unique solution $x_1(t)$, which is differentiable. Thus, as $g(x)$ is continuous, we get $g(x_1(t))$ as integrable.

Hence, for the $2nd$, we have
\begin{align*}
\frac{dx_2}{dt} &= g(x_1)x_2 \\
\implies \int_{x_{0_2}}^{x_2} \frac{dx_2}{x_2}&= \int_{t_0}^t g(x_1(t))dt \\
\implies x_2 &= x_{0_2} e^{\int_{t_0}^t g(x_1(t))dt}
\end{align*}

Comment: Now I understand. So if we remove Lipschitz condition for $f$ then we can't afford the unique solution for the IVP. Am I right?

Comment: There do exist weaker conditions on $f$ which still guarantee a unique solution for the IVP.